# Phabricator review all commits

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I have created a new git repository for a new project and added several commits. I want to request my colleague to review the entire project in Phabricator.

Is there an Arcanist command which I can issue which will cause the entire project, with all commits, to appear in Phabricator for review?

what I want to do is basically this:

```
arc diff before-first-commit
```

The first commit has id 'aabbcc'. This doesn't work:

```
arc diff aabbcc~
Usage Exception: Unable to find any git commit named 'aabbcc~' in this repository.
```

## Related question

In git, is there something like a pseudo-branch-name for the empty commit "the commit before the first commit"?

Is there a `git diff` command which will output all files in the project?
Something like:

```
git diff before-first-commit HEAD
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$ git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD | arc diff --raw
```

You can also do this:

```
$ arc diff --base arc:empty
```

But there's a bug with this in Git until https://secure.phabricator.com/D9898 lands.

(The bug is now fixed, use `arc upgrade` to upgrade.)

Answer (score 0):

For your related question, I am pretty sure you are looking for `git-whatchanged` - this will show all diffs for all commits, you run it as:

`git whatchanged`

This command will show you all diffs in sequence, but if you want to see all the files contents, well - just look at the directory with cat:

`find . -type f -exec cat {} \;`

For your original question - you might want to try this:

```
arc diff `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`
```